# Getting error after after installing app on emulator, Builds/Installs fine

Tags: android

I am trying to build this game from GitHub which i migrated to android studio at my best. After all done and this is the error i get after installing on emulator. It builds fine without any problem and installs the app on emulator but nothing happens on emulator. When i see the emulator i see the app is there but if i open it it closes after a blank screen. I got the logcat below. Since i didn't code this project i don't really understand most of it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.puzzles, PID: 3722
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.puzzles/com.example.puzzles.PuzzleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.puzzles.PuzzleActivity.decodeGameSizeFromIntent(PuzzleActivity.java:128)
        at com.example.puzzles.PuzzleActivity.onCreate(PuzzleActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3722 SIG: 9
```

Here is the PuzzleActivity.java file code....

```
package com.example.puzzles;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import com.example.puzzles.R;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PuzzleActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_PAUSED_ID = 44;
    
    GameBoard board;
    int screenOrientation;
    Bitmap sourceImage;
    
    ViewSwitcher inGameViewSwitcher;
    
    private class PauseDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{
        
        public PauseDialog(){
            super(PuzzleActivity.this, R.style.PauseMenuStyle);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.pause_menu);
            Button resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pausemenu_resumeButton);
            resumeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            Button quitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pausemenu_quitButton);
            quitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.pausemenu_resumeButton:
                this.dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.pausemenu_quitButton:
//              Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        screenOrientation = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_BOARD_ORIENTATION, 1);
  
//        String str = screenOrientation == 0 ? "PORTRAIT" : "HORIZONTAL";
//        Log.d("KAMIL", "Orientation recorded by puzzleactivity: " + str);
        
        //locking the app in needed position
        if(screenOrientation == GameBoard.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        
        //making the app full screen
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
        
        //Setting backgrounds to black.
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerLayout)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        
        inGameViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.inGameViewSwitcher);
        
        //now the fun begins :>
        
        //Crating a game board.
        board = new GameBoard(decodeGameSizeFromIntent(),
                (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerLayout),
                screenOrientation, this);
        
        sourceImage = loadBitmapFromIntent();
        
        ImageView preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previewImageView);
        preview.setImageBitmap(sourceImage);
        
        PuzzleCreator creator = new PuzzleCreator(sourceImage, board);
        board.loadTiles(creator.createPuzzle());
        board.drawBoard();
        
        
             
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_puzzle, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private com.example.puzzles.Dimension decodeGameSizeFromIntent(){
        
        com.example.puzzles.Dimension size = null;
        
        String str = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_GAMESIZE);
        
        String[] gameSizes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gamesizes);
        
        if(str.equals(gameSizes[0])) size = new com.example.puzzles.Dimension(2,3);
        else if(str.equals(gameSizes[1])) size = new com.example.puzzles.Dimension(3,5);
        else if(str.equals(gameSizes[2])) size = new com.example.puzzles.Dimension(4,7);
        else if(str.equals(gameSizes[3])) size = new com.example.puzzles.Dimension(6,10);
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Decoding game size from intent failed. String does not match.");
        
        return size;
    }
    
    private Bitmap loadBitmapFromIntent(){
        
        Bitmap selectedImage = null;
        Uri imgUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_IMGURI);
        
        try{
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
            selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Log.e("LOADING ERROR", "Cannot load picture from the URI given", ex);
        }
        
        /*
        if(selectedImage.getWidth()>selectedImage.getHeight()){
            selectedImage = BitmapOperator.rotateBitmap(selectedImage, 90);
        }*/
        
        return selectedImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        showDialog(DIALOG_PAUSED_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        
        PauseDialog dialog = new PauseDialog();
        
        if(id == DIALOG_PAUSED_ID){
            
           // dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pause_menu);
            
            
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        showDialog(DIALOG_PAUSED_ID);
    }
    
    public void inGameButtonsOnClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
        
        case R.id.previewButton:
            inGameViewSwitcher.showNext();
            break;
            
        case R.id.backToGameButton:
            inGameViewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `It builds fine without any problem and installs the app` there's a world of differences between a runtime error and a compile time error, the fact that your app builds doesn't mean it isn't going to crash

Answer (score 0):

The log tells you that in this line:

```
if(str.equals(gameSizes[0])) size = new com.example.puzzles.Dimension(2,3);
```

str Or gameSizes[0] is null, you need to debug this code and check why you getting null

Null is legit so it's not effect your build

Comment: I dont really know as i stated above that i didnt code this project. I dont know how to undo that null.

Comment: So maybe this is an issue that the owner need to fix